# How to change std::map in running program from gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have program which use some 'Log' class for logging. There is static variable inside it where log levels is.

```
class Log
{
private:
    static LogFilter filter;
    ....
```

`LogFilter` has `std::map` inside where specific log levels are stored

```
class LogFilter
{
public:
    LogFilter();

    void setLevel(LogEntryClass::EntryClass e, int level);
    int getLevel(LogEntryClass::EntryClass e);

private:
    std::map<LogEntryClass::EntryClass, int> filter;
};
```

And `LogEntryClass` is class with `EntryClass` enum inside.

```
class LogEntryClass
{
public:
    enum EntryClass
    {
        UndefinedLog = 0,
        ErrorLog,
        WarningLog,
        EventLog,
        InfoLog,
        DebugLog,
        UserLog,
        CoreInfoLog,
        CoreErrorLog,
        CoreDebugLog
    };    
    static std::string toString(const EntryClass& e);
};
```

Log levels is setting at program start up time from config file. But now I want to change log level while program is running. I can attach to it from gdb and print log levels, but I have no idea how to change values in that map

```
(gdb) print Log::filter.filter
$46 = std::map with 9 elements = {[LogEntryClass::ErrorLog] = 15, [LogEntryClass::WarningLog] = 15, 
  [LogEntryClass::EventLog] = 15, [LogEntryClass::InfoLog] = 15, [LogEntryClass::DebugLog] = 15, [LogEntryClass::UserLog] = 15, 
  [LogEntryClass::CoreInfoLog] = 0, [LogEntryClass::CoreErrorLog] = 0, [LogEntryClass::CoreDebugLog] = 0}
```

even if I take `_M_t` member of map, I can't see where is its data:

```
(gdb) print Log::filter.filter._M_t
$47 = {
  _M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<LogEntryClass::EntryClass const, int> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<LogEntryClass::EntryClass const, int> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    _M_key_compare = {<std::binary_function<LogEntryClass::EntryClass, LogEntryClass::EntryClass, bool>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_header = {_M_color = std::_S_red, _M_parent = 0xa04b70, _M_left = 0xa04cf0, _M_right = 0xa04c00}, 
    _M_node_count = 9}}


(gdb) print Log::filter.filter._M_t._M_impl
$48 = {<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<LogEntryClass::EntryClass const, int> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<LogEntryClass::EntryClass const, int> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
  _M_key_compare = {<std::binary_function<LogEntryClass::EntryClass, LogEntryClass::EntryClass, bool>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_header = {_M_color = std::_S_red, _M_parent = 0xa04b70, _M_left = 0xa04cf0, _M_right = 0xa04c00}, _M_node_count = 9}
```

I can't call any `map` methods

```
(gdb) print Log::filter.filter.begin()
One of the arguments you tried to pass to begin could not be converted to what the function wants.
(gdb) print Log::filter.filter.at(1)
One of the arguments you tried to pass to at could not be converted to what the function wants.
```

What I need is just update one integer value inside map. Is it any way to do it, even any ugly hack?

Comment: One workaround is probably adding function to your program, that does what you want, and then call it from gdb.

Comment: @dbrank0 There is such function, `void setLevel()`, but I can't call it, like can't call `find()` or `begin()` on `std::map`

Comment: Try regular function not a static method. Also make sure you compile with optimization turned off and try adding attribute used, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355196/use-gdb-to-call-a-printdebug-method.